# Can HTTP/1.1 messages be fragmented like the WebSocket protocol?

Tags: http, websocket, http2

I just read, in HTTP/2 server can do the fragmentation of the big chunk just like in the Websockets(where messages are fragmented into smaller packets for variety of reasons and one such reason was to send the ping/pong messages in between to get the connection status), Can this fragmentation be done in HTTP/1.1 as well?

Comment: You could fragment them using chunked encoding, but since there is only a single steam on HTTP/1.1 (vs. multi-stream with HTTP/2) you would only add overhead. The only reason to do it with HTTP/1.1 is when you do not know the final message length.

Comment: Ahh. So on the TCP, because of the head of line blocking we won't be able to send multiple requests per TCP connection hence no point in doing the fragmentation.